# Identify Http Request Devices

Tags: java, spring, http, web, networking

I am trying to make a spring web application and it will be requested from multiple devices (e.g. Android phones and iPhones). I need to identify the device which sends a request in order to recognize it in a later stage. How am I to achieve that in java?

A sample scenario: User signs in using a Samsung A7 and another user signs in using an iPhone 8.

I need to track and store the actions by the device. I think I need the user of a device to log in every time in order to show all actions executed by this related device. I need to recognize the device for every request here and also I will need to show to the user all logged-in devices.

I have tried to achieve this with a mac address but I think it's not effective.

when type on cmd "ipconfig/all" the following list appear but which physical address should choose between all of them ??!!!!

[image]

and i try this java code to get mac address but a NullPointerException is occurred

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(HttpRequestHelper.getRemoteAddress());

NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);

byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
```

Comment: Hi, please provide us with anything you have tried already yourself. Did you put any effort into searching for any relevant information? What did you find and what did you not find? What is it you are exactly trying to achieve? Please refer to creating a [MCVE] for more information. What do you mean by "Identify request device to recognize it later"? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Barrosy thank you for reply , i edited my question can help me ?

Comment: First of all, it seems like you made a decision to make use of the spring framework within the java language. What have you tried so far in order to tackle this problem? Please **share any java code**. You are saying you tried to use a mac address, how did you do this? I might be able to help if you could share whatever you have tried. Perhaps I can see what prevented you from continuing this work.

Comment: @Barrosy ok i have edited my question and add what is my problem exactly

Comment: The list of the information shown in the image you have provided simply shows a list of network devices detectable by your local machine as these are installed on your local machine. If you would like to get the MAC address you are [supposed](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-MAC-Address-of-Your-Computer#step-id-315) to enter `getmac /v /fo list`. To get the MAC address in Java you might be able to get this by calling the `NetworkInterface` class as described [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/). You could use the `.getHardwareAddress()` method to get it.

Comment: @Barrosy i have updated my question , can take a look

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a native app for mobile or yours is only a website?

Any way the only way is recognize user agents headers to know the device and you can use for example the device token push address that is mostly unique id.
If yours is only a website you can store the device with a generated id or random, save to your database and on browser cookies

Comment: but the cookie can deleted from the browser also

Comment: how google recognize devices that you used to login ?

Comment: Google recognize devices from native apps and user agents.
In the device list every device has a different token saved in client cookies if logged by browser or in app if connected in native app.
So they identify from the token saved that is unique for device